# How to stub a line of code inside a method called from another method using mockito

Tags: mockito

I have a class below

```
class MyClass{
    void setX(){
        statement1;
        statement2;
        obj.setY();              
    }

    void setY(){
        statement3;
        anotherObj.setZ();
    }
}
```

I would like to stub the line  anotherObj.setZ() using mockito. How do I do that.

Comment: You need to make it clearer what obj and anotherObj are. At the moment it looks like obj is an instance of MyClass. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

It depends where anotherObj is initialised. If it is initialised in the constructor of MyClass then it's easy:

```
AnotherObj anotherObjMock = Mockito.mock(AnotherObj.class);
MyClass classToTest = new MyClass(anotherObjMock);
Mockito.when(anotherObjMock.setZ()).thenReturn(whatever);
```

If it's local to the setY() method then its probably possible with PowerMock but honestly it's probably more an indicator that your code is not written well for testing and you should consider refactoring.